# internatiolization in jsp using fmt tag

Tags: java, jsp

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>JSTL fmt:message Tag</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <fmt:setLocale value="en"/>
    <fmt:setBundle basename="com.tutorialspoint.Example" var="lang"/>

    <fmt:message key="count.one" bundle="${lang}"/><br/>
    <fmt:message key="count.two" bundle="${lang}"/><br/>
    <fmt:message key="count.three" bundle="${lang}"/><br/>

    </body>
    </html>
```

i am using here fmt tag of jstl which is showing this output. 
    ???count.one???
    ???count.two???
    ???count.three???

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the associated properties file in the bundle you have mentioned

`<fmt:setBundle basename="com.tutorialspoint.Example" var="lang"/>`

If not, you need to have a properties file in com > tutorialspoint named **tutorialspoint.properties** which should contain,

```
count.one=one  
count.two=two  
count.three=three
```

And, for different `setLocale` like `fr` you should use **tutorialspoint_fr.properties** and so on.